# Possible ways to simulate tap input with android studio

Tags: java, android, remote-access, android-security, android-remoteview

I'm working on a remote access application (similiar to AnyDesk) to access mobiles on a lan network and use them with just your browser. At this point, I'm able to send the device display output via WebSockets and access to it live via a browser (from my PC). This works fine and I can see whatever I do in the mobile, but in my PC. Now, I'm trying to find a way to simulate a tap input: the client (my pc) sends the x and y coordinates to the mobile (via WebSocket) and I'm able to get those coordinates in my android code, but I can't find a way to fire this input.
Im using Adnroid Studio Hedhedog and my project is written in Java Gradle with the minSDK version 30.

I've tried whatever is in my knwoledge, as I hadn't ever programmed in Java, to get this work.

Tried using instrumentation:

```
public class InputSimulator {
    public static void simulateTap (int x, int y) {
        Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
        long timeDown = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long eventTime = timeDown + 100;
        MotionEvent motionEventDown = MotionEvent.obtain(timeDown,eventTime,MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,x,y,0);
        inst.sendPointerSync(motionEventDown);
        MotionEvent motionEventUP = MotionEvent.obtain(timeDown,eventTime,MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,x,y,0);
        inst.sendPointerSync(motionEventUp);
        motionEventDown.recycle();
        motionEventUp.recycle();
    }
}
```

This would work if android security would allow me (above 8.0 is not allowed, I think): this raises `java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission` when outside my application. Adding this permission in the MANIFEST, shows an error: `Permissions with the protection level signature, privileged or signatureOrSystem are only granted to system apps`...

Using Runtime to run a command also doesn't seem to work...

```
public class InputSimulator {
    public static void simulateTap (int x, int y) {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input " + x + " " + y);
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        Log.d("INPUT COMMAND CODE: " + exitCode); // exitCode is 0 and no tap is performed.
    }
}
```

Also tried to create an `AccesibilityService` but can't find the way to make my code work.

### TL/DR

Looking and searching through the entire web to find a way to launch a virtual input screen tap: seems impossible, even more in lasts android versions. Is there a way to perform a tap, even outside my application (maybe a service or sum)? Do I only have left to use rooted devices or install my application at a system level? Note that I don't want to send input events inside my application, but any application that the user has open.

Comment: The only way to do this is with a rooted device.  You need system level privlidges. (or you need to build your own version of AOSP so you're the OEM).

Comment: Your title is misleading you don't want to simulate input taps with Android Studio but from within an Android app. Android Studio is just the editor you use for writing your code and it manages the app build system. But it doesn't matter if you are writing apps in Android Studio or emacs, just the programming language and build system matters and that is Java + gradle + Gradle Android Plugin and not Android Studio.

Comment: No, I wan´t to find a way create a virtual tap from my code (I say virtual because it's not physical). @Robert I know Android Studio is just a tool that manages my code. The problem is that I can just simulate taps inside my application, but not in the android's ecosystem, like settings or other apps because of the android "security limitation". Now my question is: how do apps like [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/), Anydesk or [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) allow to send the input without root, as Gabe said?.

Comment: scrcpy is started via adb. adb shell has different permissions than apps that are running in a sandbox. Apps like Vysor, TeamViewer ... usually provide special app modules that have been signed by the device manufacturer and thus get system access.

Comment: So I could use wireless debugging, and send the `adb shell input tap x y` command from my pc?